# Windows audit "Removable Storage" not generating an event for file deletion

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, audit, eventviewer, removable-storage

I have a Windows 10 system on which I have enabled removable storage audits (via GPO: **Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> Audit Policies -> Object Access -> Audit Removable Storage: Success and Failure**), and also set the registry key (**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Storage\HotPlugSecureOpen = 1**).

I am getting event 4663 related to ReadData and AppendData when I create or modify a file; but I am not getting any events when I *delete* a file.

The device I am using is an Ivanti-encrypted USB flash drive, which does not show me the Security tab when I right click the drive in Windows Explorer. I believe that this precludes me from using File System audits.

How can I get Windows to log file *deletion* too?

Comment: The symptom occurs on an Ivanti encrypted drive but not on a drive not encrypted with Ivanti?

Comment: No, it happens for an unencrypted plain old USB stick too. No deletion event.